# Factory function method not updating variable

Tags: javascript

I am trying to set up a factory function with a method that would update the value for a specific variable within said factory function. This seemed like a simple thing to implement, however, whenever I test it, I'm getting the originally set value for the variable, not the updated value. I'm sure there some nuance when it comes to scoping I am missing, but what exactly is going on here?

```
const factory = () => {
let color = "black"

const changeColor = () => {
    color = "white"
}

return {color, changeColor}
}
```

Let's say I actually use the factory function somewhere:

```
const example = factory()
example.changeColor()
```

**Expected**

```
example.color === "white"
```

**Actual:**

```
example.color === "black"
```

What am I missing here? After running `changeColor()`, I would have expected `color` to switch to white, but it remains black whenever I check.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're assigning to the local variable in the closure, not to the object property that contains a copy of the original color value.

You could use a getter to make the property access the variable.

```js
const factory = () => {
  let color = "black";

  const changeColor = () => {
    color = "white"
  };

  return {
    get color() {
      return color;
    },
    changeColor
  };
}

const example = factory();
example.changeColor();

console.log(example.color);
```

But really the correct way to do this is by just having the `changeColor` method modify `this` (you have to use traditional functions rather than arrow functions for this to work).

```js
const factory = function() {
  return {
    color: "black",
    changeColor: function() {
      this.color = "white"
    }
  };
}

const example = factory();
example.changeColor();

console.log(example.color);
```

Or you can use a class or prototypes.

Comment: It looks like using `this` within the arrow function is where I tripped up - I thought using `this` might have been the solution, but when I tested it, I was still using it within the arrow function, rather than the traditional function. When I updated to a traditional function and used `this.color`, it worked as expected. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry but I think this answer is a bit misleading, this has nothing to do with assigning a local variable in closure, his assignment works, the problem is how he accesses it not a closure problem

Comment: @YairCohen That was my point. He can use a getter to make accessing the closure variable as if it's a property.

Comment: Ok I see now, I understood something else, my bad :)

Comment: You say the `this` solution is the "correct" way; is there a downside to your solution of returning `get color()`?  I just did it that way in a project and it worked great but I don't want to make a habit out of it if it might cause issues later

Answer (score 1):

You are return the value for color, not the reference to the color variable itself, so closure won't be in effect in this case and you will always get the initial value 'black'. You could resolve this by saving these to the context and init with `new` (provide that you use `function` rather than arrow function)

```js
const factory = function () {
  this.color = "black";

  this.changeColor = () => {
    this.color = "white";
  };
};

const example = new factory();
example.changeColor();

console.log(example.color);
```

Ref: [`new` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new)

> The new operator lets developers create an instance of a user-defined object type or of one of the built-in object types that has a constructor function.